# Modify Javascript Variable with URL Exploit

Tags: web-browser, exploit, javascript, html, url

Is it possible to set a javascript variable through the URL?

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to modify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = 0;

</script>
```

Is there a way to modify that variable through a browser, for instance, **www.somewebsite.com + *(something that changes 'x' variable)***?

**Related on Stack Exchange:**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023761/modify-javascript-variable-with-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible without an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerability. If such a thing were generally possible, XSS would run rampant and you could execute any arbitrary code on any page, which would be bad.

Now if the code had a reflected XSS attack vector, or an DOM-based XSS attack vector, the the URL could be used to deliver a JavaScript payload. Of course, this would only be possible if the server-side or JavaScript code had such a security vulnerability (if your code makes that possible, then you should fix it).

Answer (score 1):

Similar attacks are possible, *without XSS*.

Say the code was

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = 0;

// Some processing

x=395;

</script>
```

If the attacker wants the value of `x` not to be affected by the `x=395` they could use the browser's anti-XSS filter in order to filter out the code.

e.g. By creating a crafted link to send to their victim:

```
example.com/page.html?param=x%3d395%3b
```

The XSS filter will detect that the parameter value is reflected in the output (`x=395;`), and block execution of it.

Therefore, the original value of `x` will remain.

In order to mitigate this, set the user's browser's XSS filter to block rather than to filter using [security headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project#tab=Headers):

```
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```