# Should untrusted strings be sanitized server-side if they're inserted into the document body through document.createTextNode?

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, data-validation

Chat webapp. Clients (that is, web browsers) send messages to the server, which the server broadcasts to all connected clients. Client-side code looks like this:

```
let p = document.createElement('p')
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message))
document.getElementById('chatbox').appendChild(p)
```

Where `message` is the string received from the server.

The problem here is that [it is strongly recommended](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/current-best-practices-to-prevent-persistent-xss-attacks) to sanitize server-side untrusted data before inserting it into document body, by removing special characters (`<`, `>`, `"`, etc) and replacing them with appropriate HTML entities. **I was told the above code was vulnerable to XSS if this is not done**.

However, such sanitization seems to lead to incorrect displaying of messages if `document.createTextNode` is used. [Unlike `innerHTML`, `document.createTextNode` displays special characters **verbatim** and does **not** interpret them as HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/3e6pngt4/11/). Thus server-side sanitization that changes aforementioned characters to HTML entities **will cause the clients to display the entities, not the characters the enities are supposed to represent**.

As such I do not believe that such validation is necessary nor correct when `document.createTextNode()` is used.

However, I was told that it is nevertheless always necessary to sanitize untrusted strings server side. I was told that escaping these characters server-side was **always** necessary. In that case, am I supposed to stop using `document.createTextNode()` and start using `innerHTML` instead? That seems odd to me because I've always thought `innerHTML` to be one of the *least* secure features of JavaScript, which should not be used with untrusted content.

Answer (score 1):

The input to `createTextNode`, `textContent`, and the non-standard `innerText` all take plain JavaScript strings. You do not need to and should not encode that input as HTML, plain JS strings are all you need.

That being said, you do still need to properly encode the message from the server. If you are outputting the text as HTML, you would encode it with HTML entities. If you are outputting the message as JavaScript or JSON, you would typically encode it with a JSON encoder. The correct encoding depends on the context it is output and is not always HTML.